# import model in Django to services django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import

I am facing the following problem.

On my Django project, I created a **services.py** file in the "**resume**" app directory, in which I want to place some project business logic.

Below is the project structure:

[image]

In this file (**services.py**) I import the models:

```
# services.py

from models import PersonalData


def get_personal_data():
    list_data = PersonalData.objects.all()
    return list_data
```

Then I get the following exception:

**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.**

Below is the entire Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python_projects\my_site\mysite\resume\services.py", line 9, in <module>
    from mysite.resume.models import PersonalData
  File "D:\python_projects\my_site\mysite\resume\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class PersonalData(models.Model):
  File "D:\virtualenv\mysite\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 129, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\virtualenv\mysite\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "D:\virtualenv\mysite\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 137, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "D:\virtualenv\mysite\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "D:\virtualenv\mysite\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My **INSTALLED_APPS** in settings.py has this **app**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'resume.apps.ResumeConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

One solution I found is to call **django.setup()** and pass the path to **settings.py**. After that I wrote the following in **services.py**:

```
# services.py

import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_site.settings')
django.setup()

from models import PersonalData


def get_personal_data():
    list_data = PersonalData.objects.all()
    return list_data
```

After that I got another exception:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_site'**

Below is the whole Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python_projects\my_site\mysite\resume\services.py", line 6, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "D:\virtualenv\mysite\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\virtualenv\mysite\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "D:\virtualenv\mysite\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\virtualenv\mysite\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_site'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't understand why it doesn't find the **my_site** module, if it exists. A similar environment variable is set in **manage.py**:

```
# manage.py

def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_site.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also I tried setting environment variable in **cmd**:

D:\python_projects\my_site>set SJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = my_site.settings

But is didn't help as well. I think i tried all answers is Stack Overflow but nothing work

Help please, what should i do and what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`my_site` is project, instead, you need to deal with app `resume` which is your app.

and you have problem with models import as well.

```
from .models import PersonalData
```

and remove other unnecessary codes to django.setup() and environment variable for the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

Another mistake I can see is typo mistake on project setting. You projectname is mysite not my_site

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
```